# What is the payload syntax for iOS push notifications in firebase cloud functions?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-functions, apple-push-notifications

In our React app, we try to implement Push notifications. They work on Android and when sending them via Firebase console they also do in iOS.
But if we do it with a cloud function, it only sends them to the Android phones
We cant find the correct information about the syntax for iOS. Is it different to the payload syntax for Android?
We have installed the certificates for development and production and we get the tokens correctly.
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#customize-messages-across-platforms) you can find more details how the payloads should look like.

> Whenever you want to send values only to particular platforms, don't use common fields; use platform-specific fields. For example, to send a notification only to iOS and web but not to Android, you must use two separate sets of fields, one for iOS and one for web.

Do you use the right tokens to send the notifications to the iOS devices?

Comment: We got the apns tokens and then found out, that we have to convert them to fcm tokens. This was tricky, but as soon as we had them we had the same problem again.

Comment: Do you use the offical Firebase SDK to get the tokens?